# No new object passed to cocoon callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-events, cocoon-gem

I am using [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), and have the following callback:

```
$(document).bind('cocoon:after-insert', function(e,inserted_item) {
    alert('Inserted!');
});
```

The alert fires as expected, but `inserted_item` is undefined. `e` is fully formed and available. What am I missing?

I have also attempted to replace `document` with a class selector, but there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the gem from github? E.g. in your gemfile write:

```
gem 'cocoon', :git => 'https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon'
```

The feature you mention is not yet released, will happen somewhere this weekend. Want to fix one other open issue first.

Comment: I see. I just assumed that the GitHub Readme would match the current gem version. Thanks again for cocoon. It is by far the best solution for nested forms.

Comment: How can I get the callbacks to work on an edit action? I have tried changing the js to `$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert','.selector',function(...` with no luck.

Comment: Hmmm bit cryptic. So I am assuming it works on the `new` but not the `edit`? If so: normally you should render the same form, no? If not, what is the difference? For cocoon there is no difference at all between a new or edit.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I am rendering the same form partial and all of the same nested partials. The callbacks work on new but not on edit, and I assumed that it had something to do with the sequence of rendering and binding.

Comment: I just noticed that my jQuery validator is also not working on the edit action. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? There are no javascript errors in the console, and I am positive that the same partials are being rendered in both cases.

Comment: I would propose starting a new question, so you can show a bit more code there.

Comment: I finally realized that I was relying on the `.new_{model_name}` class that Rails applies to the top-level parent form. Obviously this changes to `.edit_{model_name}` on the edit action, but you don't see this in the hand-written code. Sorry for the false alarm. The only other difference is that there doesn't seem to be any `cocoon:after-insert` event fired when the edit form is first rendered (even though it contains nested children). This makes sense because the nested model is already inserted before rendering. Thanks again.